# Aggregate Root including tremendous number of children

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

I wonder how to model Calendar using DDD and CQRS. My problem consist in increasing number of events. I consider Calendar as Aggregate Root which contains Events (Calendar Events). I dont want to use ReadSide in my Commands but I need way to check events collisions at domain level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I wonder how to model Calendar using DDD and CQRS. My problem consist in increasing number of events.

The most common answer to "long lived" aggregates is to break that lifetime into episodes.  An example of this would be the temporary accounts that an accountant will close at the [end of the fiscal year](http://www.accountingcoach.com/blog/closing-entries).

In your specific case, probably not "the Calendar" so much as "the February calendar", the "the March calendar", and so on, at whatever grain is appropriate in your domain.

> Im not sure if Im right about DDD aproach in terms of validation. I believe the point is not to allow the model to enter into invalid state

Yes, but invalid state is a tricky thing to define.  Udi Dahan offered [this observation](http://udidahan.com/2010/08/31/race-conditions-dont-exist/)

> A microsecond difference in timing shouldn’t make a difference to core business behaviors.

More succinctly, processing command A followed by processing command B produces a valid state, then it should also be true that you end up processing command B first, and then A.

Let's choose your "event collisions" example.  Suppose we handle two commands `scheduleMeeting(A)` and `scheduleMeeting(B)`, and the domain model understands that `A` and `B` *collide*.  Riddle: how do we make sure the calendar stays in a valid state?

Without loss of generality, we can flip a coin to decide which command arrives first.  My coin came up tails, so command `B` arrives first.

```
on scheduleMeeting(B):
    publish MeetingScheduled(B)
```

Now the command for meeting `A` arrives.  If your valid calendars do not permit conflicts, then your implementation needs to look something like

```
on scheduleMeeting(A):
    throw DomainException(A conflicts with B)
```

On the other hand, if you embrace the idea that the commands arrive shouldn't influence the outcome, then you need to consider another approach.  Perhaps

```
on scheduleMeeting(A)
    publish MeetingScheduled(A)
    publish ConflictDetected(A,B)
```

That is, the Calendar aggregate is modeled to track not only the scheduled events, but also the conflicts that have arisen.

See also: [aggregates and RFC 2119](http://cascadefaliure.blogspot.com/2017/02/aggregates-and-rfc-2119.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your idea about spliting calendar into seperate months seems perfectly valid to me. Im not sure if Im right about DDD aproach in terms of validation. I believe the point is not to allow the model to enter into invalid state - which implies necessity of knowing all own events by Calendar (as Agreggate Root).

Comment: I think you need to explain a bit more in detail how the system could leverage eventual consistency, because the way you described it, you still need large aggregate boundaries in order to detect that a conflict even occurred. With eventual consistency, events could be separate aggregates and you could get rid of the collection of events in the calendar entirely (replacing it with a query).

Comment: When I was doing some sort of resource management, I ended up having a concept of Day. Not to much of my surprise, other practitioners have came to the same conclusion. You can have both Event and Day, and check if they are mutually compatible (day has availability and event can land to days).

Answer (score 3):

Event could also an be an Aggregate root. I don't know your business constraint but I think that if two Events colide you could  notify the user somehow to take manual actions. Otherwise, if you *really really* need them not to colide you could use snapshots to speed up the enormous Calendar AR.

> I dont want to use ReadSide in my Commands but I need way to check events collisions at domain level.

You cannot query the read model inside the aggregate command handler. For the colision detection I whould create a special `DetectColisionSaga`  that  subscribes to the `EventScheduled` event and that whould check (possible async if are many Events) if a colision had occurred and notify the user somehow.

Comment: Thanks, but is accessing read side from the domain considered good practice at all?

Comment: What do you mean by "domain"? Do you mean the write side?

Comment: Yes, basically in terms of this question I mean write side. As far as I grasp Commands those are supposed to be executed (by handlers) directly on domain models.

Comment: Read models, projections or whatever lookup mechanisms you need to model your domain are part of the domain. The domain can contain this kind of state. These may be very specialised projections and not useful for say displaying in a UI to the user. Materialised views on the read side will be created for this and they are not part of the domain.